# How to rerender component after setState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'd like to react rerender component after every state edit.

App component:

```
  let [cur1, setCur1] = useState('USD')
  let [cur2, setCur2] = useState('EUR')
  let [result, setResult] = useState(0)
  let currenciesArr = [cur1, cur2]

  async function getRate(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    setCur1(cur1 = e.target.cur1.value)
    setCur2(cur2 = e.target.cur2.value)
    let amount = e.target.amount.value
    const api_url = await fetch(`https://free.currconv.com/api/v7/convert?q=${cur1}_${cur2}&compact=ultra&apiKey=${API_KEY}`)
    const data = await api_url.json()
    await setResult(convert(amount, data))
  }
```

I have used Context.Provider for rerender, but it doesn't work.

```
return (
    <Context.Provider value={{currenciesArr}}>
    <div>
      <Choose getRate={getRate} chooseCur={chooseCur} chooseCur2={chooseCur2}/>
      <ShowRate currencies={currenciesArr} result={result}/>
    </div>
  </Context.Provider>
)
```

Component that need to rerender

```
function Choose(props) {
  const cProps = useContext(Context)
  console.log(cProps.currenciesArr);
  return(
    <div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={ props.chooseCur } name='RUB'>RUB</button>
        <button onClick={ props.chooseCur } name='AUD'>AUD</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={ props.chooseCur2 } name='EUR'>EUR</button>
        <button onClick={ props.chooseCur2 } name='GBP'>GBP</button>
      </div>
      <form onSubmit={props.getRate}>
        {cProps.currenciesArr.map((item,i) => {
          return(
            <input type='text' key={i} name={'cur'+(i+1)} defaultValue={item}></input>
          )
        })
        }
        <input type='text' name='amount' defaultValue='1'></input>
        <button onClick={(e)=>{console.log(e.target)}} ></button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Button with prop `props.chooseCur` setting state in App component

```
function chooseCur(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    setCur1(e.target.name)
  }
  function chooseCur2(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    setCur2(e.target.name)
  }
```

and i'd like to "choose" component will rerender after setState.

Comment: You don't need a context here. Context is for sharing state across many disconnected components. Your state is stored in `App` and the component you want to use the state in is a child of `App`.

Comment: You should be using `const` instead of `let` when creating state values. If the `Choose` component needs to use `currenciesArr`, you should pass it as a prop.

Comment: i passed it as a prop, but it didn't work. So, i read it in React documentation:"Every Context object comes with a Provider React component that allows consuming components to subscribe to context changes." I thought it could solve the problem.

Comment: Could you post a working example on CodeSandbox and I will take a look?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-star-sdotu?file=/src/index.js

Comment: A possible implementation could be like https://codesandbox.io/s/react-currency-converter-demo-qenjo - I'll have a look at your Sandbox later today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First `currenciesArr` should be part of the state as `const [currenciesArr, setCurrenciesArr] = useState([cur1, cur2])`

Next, you need to call `setCurrenciesArr` in your `chooseCur2` functions. I used a restructuring assignment to get the value of name inside the function. Hooks are called when the event loop is complete. See [Capbase Medium post](https://medium.com/capbase-engineering/asynchronous-functional-programming-using-react-hooks-e51a748e6869) for more information on hooks and the event loop.

In choose.js

You need to use `value` in your input instead of `defaultValue` and set it as readonly to prevent receiving a warning about setting the value.

> Default value provides the value if none is present.

See the following [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/long-rain-8vyuh) for a working version.

https://codesandbox.io/s/long-rain-8vyuh

Comment: Got it! Thank you!